# Data Type Mismatch error in criteria expression" error

Tags: sql, ms-access

When trying to run below script i am getting:

> Data Type Mismatch error in criteria expression

```
UPDATE 14052017 SET [14052017].[Customer label] = [14052017].[Customer label]
WHERE ((([14052017].[Customer label])=Replace([14052017].[Customer label],"-","")));
```

Comment: `UPDATE [14052017]`

Comment: That query doesn't make sense. It just "updates" some labels to the values they already have.

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* want this:

```
UPDATE [14052017] 
SET [Customer label] = Replace([Customer label],"-","")
WHERE [Customer label] LIKE "*-*"
```

Otherwise, as Gustav wrote, your UPDATE wouldn't change any data.

If all rows have the "-", you can omit the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks guys. i overlooked the replace function placement. thanks again for correction.